# Error Shown on Front End of Magento 1.9 Please specify the product's option(s). While Add to Cart Configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, custom-options

I am new to Magento and I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 community edition. My website was working fine before some days. I have added one custom option of Gift Wrap Requirement for Customers. For this I used Radio Button as you can see in below Image
 [image]

After that, If we add to cart any Configurable product after selecting Size, then it gives error Please specify the product's option(s).

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try after removing the custom option again?

Comment: Yes @SukumarGorai, I tried after removing custom option from 2 products, but still I am facing issue

Comment: Can you share screenshot?

Comment: Yes Sure... PFB URL of screenshot

Comment: https://prnt.sc/jp47kw

Comment: Not from the admin. From the front end where you are getting error

Comment: @SukumarGorai sir, https://prnt.sc/jp47kw is screenshot of frontend.

Comment: Why not you are sharing the whole screen?

Comment: Due to privacy I have not shared the whole screen. Let me make one more configurable product with dummy content. Then I'll share full screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeh! my issue has been resolved. I have issue of that when we do add to cart, then it switch over from secure connection to Unsecure.